# host can choose which system calls pass to each webassembly module

Tags: sandbox, webassembly, blazor-webassembly, isolation, wasmtime

part of the talk of Lin Clark in https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/03/standardizing-wasi-a-webassembly-system-interface/:

> It also gives us sandboxing because the host can choose which wasi-core functions to pass in — so, which system calls to allow — on a program-by-program basis. This preserves security.

she says host can choose which system calls pass to each `wasm` module. for example `read()` system call passes to `module A` and `write()` system call to `module B`.

is it implemented in `wasmtime` or `lucet` or other runtimes? or is it just a dream without implementation in real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is implemented in all runtimes implementing `wasi`. The reason is that this feature is related to import/export mechanism of WebAssembly.